# Breakpoint does not work in a websocket deployed in Wildfly 8.x

Tags: spring, websocket, breakpoints, wildfly

I am having a problem deploying my spring websocket service in a `Wildfly 8.x server`.

I have two Java services running in the wildfly server, one of them is working great but the other one (the websocket one), despite is deployed correctly does not stop in the breakpoints. In fact, when I set the breakpoint it seems as if the server was off.

The deployment folder of my wildfly server created the two directories, one of each services.

I am using `jdk 1.8` and `Maven 3.2.3`.

Thanks in advance for any help!